# can i generate an image using python within jupyter

Tags: graphics, pygame, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to use python code to create an image (in memory ) and display it within a jupyter notebook?

I want to be able to display some grid of pixels so I need to be able to set its size and be able to select which of its pixels is lit and which is not.

eventually I would like to make it animate display a series of calculate pixel images.

I tried using :

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen= pg.display.set_mode([225,150])
r=pg.Color('red')
w=pg.Color('white')
data=[
    [r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r],
    [r,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,r],
    [r,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,r],
    [r,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,r],
    [r,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,r],
    [r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r]
]
for y,row in enumerate(data):
    for x,colour in enumerate(row):
        rect = pg.Rect(x*25,y*25,25,25)
        screen.fill(colour,rect=rect)

pg.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()
    CLOCK.tick(30)
```

Which I grabbed from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b84EywkQ3HI but it does not seem to do anything in jupyter.

Comment: I'm not sure pygame will be able to do it, but jupyter typically comes installed with a lot of libraries that help with that sort of thing. I would look into pyplot, which is part of the matplotlib library.

Also check this post: http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-notebooks/

Comment: hmm.. I am not sure I can use pyplot to do what I want, its not graphs that I am interested in showing. but the post you mentioned made me think that I might be able to use HTML with a canvas for this (maybe) though I would prefer a more direct approach.

Comment: maybe someone has another idea?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is incomplete. The complete and working example is as follows:

```py
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *              # <---

pg.init()
screen= pg.display.set_mode([225,150])
r=pg.Color('red')
w=pg.Color('white')
data=[
    [r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r],
    [r,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,r],
    [r,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,r],
    [r,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,r],
    [r,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,r],
    [r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r]
]
for y,row in enumerate(data):
    for x,colour in enumerate(row):
        rect = pg.Rect(x*25,y*25,25,25)
        screen.fill(colour,rect=rect)

CLOCK = pg.time.Clock()                  # <---
pg.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()
    CLOCK.tick(30)
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)